# How to make NSImage automatically scale to NSImageView?

Tags: cocoa, core-graphics

I am trying to implement a programatic image that is drawn by a `draw` method which is capable of drawing a perfect image at any resolution. Think of a programmatic texture that can be sized up to fill any area without stretching or interpolation.

To that end I have created a custom `NSImageRep` which implements the drawing code. The code inside this method has access to the size of the image rep and so it can redraw itself for each size. To display the image I assign this `NSImageRep` to an `NSImage`, and then I pass that to an `NSImageView`.

Now the problem is that the `NSImage` won't resize. I mean it stretches and interpolates to fill the `NSImageView`, but the size of the `NSImage` doesn't change, and so its `NSImageRep` drawing code always draws into the size with which the `NSImage` was originally created. I can change the size of the `NSImage` and it will

In other words I have successfully implemented an `NSImage` which can draw itself properly at any size (without interpolation). So my question is, how do I make an `NSImage` automatically resize itself to match the size of the `NSImageView` it is placed into?

Ideally I would like to implement this as a category on `NSImage` but I'm not sure how to proceed.

N.B. I know that it sounds like I just want to implement a custom `NSView` but the big picture is that I'm trying to replicate the `resizableImageWithCapInsets:` method from iOS' `UIImage` and create an implementation for OS X' `NSImage`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forget about `NSImageRep`

What you want to use is just `NSImage`

```
+ (id)imageWithSize:(NSSize)size flipped:(BOOL)drawingHandlerShouldBeCalledWithFlippedContext drawingHandler:(BOOL (^)(NSRect dstRect))drawingHandler
```

This will enable you to do what you want.